# C: Reading multiple areas into an array and finding the largest value

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm attempting to find the largest value in an array. I'm given a set of areas (the input), which for now is:

```
4.5
19.59
1.92
```

These areas need to be read into an array using `scanf` and then from there I need to find the largest value (area) in that array. It should also be known that there can only be maximum of 100 areas that can be read into the array. So later on I may need to read in 5 or 20 or 99 etc... into the array.

If anybody could give me a hand it'd be much appreciated, I'm new to programming and don't really know where to begin.

Comment: How do you know when the input has ended?

Comment: The input has ended when there are no more areas left to read in i.e. all the values in the column have been read into the array. It's a finite given input of between 1 and 100 values.

Comment: There is no way you detect whether there is more input like that(unless there are 100 inputs). There should be something that indicates the end of input. Something like `EOF`.

Comment: That's sort of why I posted the question. I have code that has computed the area but I need to read that area into an array some how.

Comment: Do the user input these values? or are they read/redirected from a file?

Comment: redirected from a file

Comment: You could've said that in your question. I'm posting an answer.

Comment: Is there really a need to store *all* the values?

Comment: I would like to store all the values so I can find the largest area of the all the given areas in the array

Comment: There is no need to do that. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have said in a comment that the data is redirected from a file. You have also said that you need to find the biggest value. In that case, `EOF` is the indication used to denote the end of input. Also, you don't need to store all the values.

You need to read the values one by one, storing just the largest one. See the below code:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(FILENAME,"r");
if(fp == NULL)
   Handle_error(); // or exit(0);

double largest=0,temp;
while( (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &temp) == 1)
{
    if( temp > largest)
        largest = temp;
}

printf("Largest area = %f" , largest);
```

The `while` loop will break when

1. The end of file(`EOF`) is encountered
2. Any invalid data(like characters) is found

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    double v, max_v = 0.0, array[100];
    int i = 0, n, state;

    while(i < 100){
        if(EOF == (state = scanf("%lf", &v)))
            break;
        else {
            int ch, invalid = 0;
            while((ch = fgetc(stdin))!='\n' && ch != EOF){
                if(!isspace(ch))
                    invalid = 1;
            }
            if(invalid || v < 0)
                printf("invalid!\n");//skip
            else {
                array[i++] = v;
                if(max_v < v)
                    max_v = v;
            }
        }
    }
    n = i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%f\n", array[i]);
    }
    printf("Largest area = %f\n", max_v);

    return 0;
}
```